# Opportunity validation rule not firing when fields are blank

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I'm trying to get this validation rule on Opportunity to fire off whenever StageName = 'Decline to Bid' AND either Lost_Reason__c(Picklist) is blank OR Lost_Details__c(Text) is blank. 
In other words, Lost Reason and Lost Details must be filled in when the StageName changes to 'Decline to Bid'. Here's what I got so far:

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Decline to Bid'),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Lost_Reason__c)),
ISBLANK(Lost_Details__c)
)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Edit:
I tried the formula provided by Suri, not working. Made sure there're no blank spaces and no typos. The rule is active.

[image: Criteria 1]

[image: Criteria 2]

Comment: is this field a picklist Lost_Reason__c

Comment: @Suri Yes it is.

Comment: silly question, is the rule active?

Comment: @rao Yes the rule is active.

Comment: Answer I gave is working you can change your validation rule as I posted

Comment: @leemeister Edit the validation and check if there are any extra blank spaces before, between or after 'Decline to Bid', the text may look right in the view screen but may contain extra blanks when you click edit on the validation rule and see the criteria

Comment: @leemeister another silly one, you are sure the saved record has stage = Decline to Bid, and the other 2 values as blank right? Just making sure you are not populating BOTH the fields Lost_Reason__c,Lost_Details__c.

Comment: Judging the the description in your question, wouldn't you want AND(ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Decline to Bid'), then OR(ISBLANK(TEXT(Lost_Reason__c)),
ISBLANK(Lost_Details__c)
))? So that if either field is blank, the validation rule's triggered.

Comment: @leemeister please mark the answer solved

Comment: Please don't validate multiple fields using OR this way-- it creates a poor UX experience. See my answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks. The error will specify what fields that need input on top of the page so it won't be confusing.

Comment: @leemeister It's your UI to do with as you want, but I've seen objects with, say, 300 fields, and an error at the top of the page tells you that one of those fields is bad. Don't make the user search for it. A nice, red bar next to a field is worth more than a field label at the top of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So that the validation rule fires if either field is blank you'd need to use

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Decline to Bid'),
OR(
ISBLANK(TEXT(Lost_Reason__c)),
ISBLANK(Lost_Details__c)
)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not validate multiple fields in a single validation rule, because this will look weird when the user triggers the rule. Your only choices are to put it at the top of the page, which won't highlight a specific field, or you can place it on either the reason or detail field, which will look weird when the value is populated but the message says it needs to be. Instead, *use two rules* to accomplish your task.

Rule #1:

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Decline to Bid'), ISBLANK(TEXT(Lost_Reason__c)))
```

Rule #2:

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Decline to Bid'), ISBLANK(Lost_Details__c))
```

Attach each rule to the correct field so the user can immediately see which field is in error when they are prevented from saving.

Answer (score 0):

The formula should look like this, make sure the rule is active

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Decline to Bid'),
ISPICKVAL(Lost_Reason__c,''),
ISBLANK(Lost_Details__c)
)
```

Comment: The op's rule looks fine too, you can use ISBLANK(text(picklist_field)) to validate if picklist value is blank

Comment: ya it looks like he is doing Typo error while refering to this value -->Decline to Bid

Comment: @Suri Thanks but it's still not firing. Please see edits above.

Comment: AND(  ISPICKVAL(Lost_Reason__c,''), ISBLANK(Lost_Details__c) ) just to make sure there  may be any problem with the stage name change the rule as in the comment, if it fires then check the API name and Decline to Bid picklist values are correct as you were refering