# Validation Rules: If the status is change

Tags: validation, validation-rule

EDIT:

I have break down the validation and I found where it is failing:
 the below validation works fine and it fires when I try to save the blank:

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Completed"),
 (ISBLANK(Completion_Date__c ) 
))
```

This validation rules does not fire:

```
AND (
ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Completed"),
(ISBLANK (Completion_Date__c )),
(ISBLANK (Last_Completion_Date__c))
)
```

So the question is: How can I had more fields if the status changed to `Completed`?

I have the validation rule that is ACTIVE and does not fire when I test it:

here is what I have:

```
AND (
ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Completed"),
(ISBLANK (Completion_Date__c )),
(ISBLANK (Last_Completion_Date__c))
)
```

the `Completion_Date__c` & `Last_Completion_Date__c` is required field only when the `Status__c` is changed to `Completed`

Comment: Did you try using ISNULL() ? over ISBLANK()

Comment: tried `isnull` did not work either

Comment: Try this - `AND(ISCHANGED(Status__c), ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Completed"),
(ISBLANK (Completion_Date__c )),
(ISBLANK (Last_Completion_Date__c))
)`

Comment: @Sanjay: Did not fire the validation

Comment: At this point you need to break down your logic and check for the conditions with just Completion Date and Last Completion Date irrespective of the Status. If it works then probably the IsPickVal() maybe causing issue. Try using Contains() as well IsPickVal(contains(Status__c,"Completed")

Comment: will try your suggestion, is there a way I can do debug the validation rules? I'm new to SF and I felt like you hitting the black box without knowing what exactly the values are returning

Comment: Setup>Monitor>Logs>Debug Logs       >       Create a log under your name and try to trigger your validation by editing and saving the record. A log will be created in the debug logs, you can check there

Comment: I have update my question, please have a look

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opportunity validation rule not firing](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79757/opportunity-validation-rule-not-firing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is I able to solve the above validation. I hope it will help somebody who is looking.

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Completed")
,
OR(
 ISBLANK(Completion_Date__c),
 ISBLANK(Last_Completion_Date__c) //you can multiple fields just by adding here....   
))
```